# Making a generic parameterized type of anything

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, for-loop, each

So I am trying to make a parameterized type that will work for anytype in Java this includes anything that is an object, and also the primitives types. How would i go about doing this?

Ok, suppose I want the target of a for-each to be a primitive, so its

for(int i : MyClass)

something like that. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4):

Going from your comment on Bozho's answer, you probably want something like this:

```
interface MyInterface<T> extends Iterable<T> {
}
```

and no, you can't do that for primitive types. You could simulate an iterator for a primitive type, but it will never really be Iterable, as in, usable in a for-each loop.

Comment: `T` cannot be a primitive type.

Comment: well, he referred to my answer where the primitives issues is explained.

Comment: Ok, suppose I want the target of a for-each to be a primitive, so its
for(int i : MyClass) something like that. Is this possible to do?

Comment: You can't do for (int i: MyClass). MyClass would have to be an int or Integer. You could use the generic type T in a loop though.
for(T var: myIterableOfTypeT).

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing something but why don't you just implement [`Iterable<T>`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)?

Comment: it's the question, rather than you, that is missing something

Answer (score 1):

```
public MyClass<E>
```

it doesn't include primitive types, i.e. you can't declare `MyClass<int> myobj;`, but you can use the wrappers (`java.lang.Integer`, etc)

Comment: well i tried it and it didn't work. What I should have said, is that I am trying to make an interface generic. The interface is iterable.

Comment: ah, so it's not your class, but an existing one. Well, Iterable IS generic, so what exactly 'didn't work'. Are you using Java 1.5+ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this sort of thing, usefully, for primitive types. If you are 'lucky' you get evil autoboxing, and if you are unlucky you might get protests from the compiler. If you look at GNU Trove or Apache Commons Primitives, you'll see the parallel universe that results from the desire to do the equivalent of the collections framework on primitive types.

I suppose that if you are sure that the overhead of autoboxing is acceptable to you it might make sense, but I can't get over my tendency to find it revolting.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but I suspect it is not what you are really after...

```
final List< Integer> list;

...

for(final int i : list)
{
}
```